# Apache HttpClient SelfSigned certificates

Tags: ssl, apache-httpclient-4.x, self-signed

A self signed certificate is one that is not signed by a Certificate Authority(CA). JAVA stores the certificates of most of the CA (here jre/lib/security/cacerts) and so if you want to connect to an https site with certificate signed by a CA there is no special code for it. (the same code for http call would work)

So basically

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(https_url);
httpclient.execute(httpGet)
```

But if we have a self signed certificate then we would need to configure the client and make it work. Otherwise we would see

> sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
>
> javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'localhost' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer ...

How to configure http client for this case?

Answer (score 1):

httpclient 4.x

## Approach 1

Configure the TrustStrore through debug options

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/Users/amodpandey/.keystore
```

Java is able to read the truststore even without passing the password (password of the truststore)

But even after this you might face

> javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'localhost' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer ...

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient =
  HttpClientBuilder.create()
        .setSSLHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {              
          @Override
          public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
            return true;
          }
        })
        .build();
```

And it works..

## Approach 2

Put it all in the code

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient =
  HttpClientBuilder.create()
        .setSslcontext(SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(new File(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("keystore").getFile())).build())
        .setSSLHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {              
          @Override
          public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
            return true;
          }
        })
        .build();
```

## Approach 3

While using a connection manager

The setSslcontext and setSSLHostnameVerifier are ignore when using

```
.setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
```

So connection manager should be configured

```
Files.copy(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("keystore"), Paths.get(URI.create("file:/tmp/keystore")),
    StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> socketFactoryRegistry =
    RegistryBuilder
        .<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
        .register(
            "https",
            new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(SSLContextBuilder.create()
                .loadTrustMaterial(new File("/tmp/keystore")).build(),
                new HostnameVerifier() {
                  @Override
                  public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                    return true;
                  }
                })).register("http", PlainConnectionSocketFactory.INSTANCE).build();

PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager =
    new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(socketFactoryRegistry);

CloseableHttpClient httpClient =
    HttpClientBuilder.create()
        .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
        .build();
```

## Note

- *-Djavax.net.debug=all* debug option is very helpful to see the certificates being used
- The SSLContext uses File and if we plan to package the certificate with the code in a Jar then we would need to create a file to pass it to the File object (it does not for files inside the jar)

  Files.copy(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("keystore"),Paths.get(URI.create("file:/tmp/utskeystore")),StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING)